# ListView in UWP

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I am trying to Align my ListView items in dynamic way without setting explicitly Width for them. The problem i am getting is aligning them the attribute name that is above them. i.e attribute Name should have Coke below it, Quantity should have Integer value number and Subtotal should have floating points below it.
if i resize my Windows the ListView should also change with the respective attribute name but it doesn't. I have tried RelativePanel, ListBox for them but nothing works without explicity giving a width which i want it to be dynamic.

```
<Grid Grid.Column="2" Margin="5,0,5,0">

            <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden">
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource MyTextBlock1}" FontSize="20" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,0,10">Order Summary</TextBlock>
                    <RelativePanel>
                        <TextBlock Name="ItemName" Style="{StaticResource MyTextBlock1}" FontSize="12">Name</TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock Name="ItemPrice" Style="{StaticResource MyTextBlock1}" FontSize="12" RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel="True">SubTotal</TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock Name="ItemQuantity" Style="{StaticResource MyTextBlock1}" Margin="0,0,10,0" FontSize="12" RelativePanel.LeftOf="ItemPrice">Quantity</TextBlock>
                    </RelativePanel>

                    <ListView ItemsSource="{x:Bind dumbList}">
                        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:Dumb">
                                <Grid Width="200">
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind name}"/>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind id}" Grid.Column="1"/>
                                    <TextBlock Name="Quatity" Text="{x:Bind price}" Grid.Column="2"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

[CLICK HERE!! for the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QFgiz.png)

Answer (score 0):

Edit:

You can create one item with the DataTemplate layout above the listview.

To avoid setting explicitly the Width, you can set the HorizontalAlignment to Stretch (similiar to Android XML fill_parent) and use Margin.

Example:

```
<Grid 
    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
    Margin="12,12,12,12"
    Height="100">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Text="Name"/>
    <TextBlock Text="Quantity" Grid.Column="1"/>
    <TextBlock Text="SubTotal" Grid.Column="2"/>
</Grid>

<ListView ItemsSource="{x:Bind dumbList}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:Dumb">
            <Grid
                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                Margin="12,12,12,12"
                Height="100">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind name}"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind id}" Grid.Column="1"/>
                <TextBlock Name="Quatity" Text="{x:Bind price}" Grid.Column="2"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Comment: Hi Alexandre! Thanks for your reply!
The issue i am facing is the alignment only. I want my alignment same that i have shown in the picture that i have attached. Just want some spacing of my desire and also it should be dynamic in nature as relative panel is dynamic.
I have no issue in getting data into my listview.

Comment: Hi Muhammad! I edited my answer, my first one wasn't very good. You can use above the ListView a Grid exactly like your DataTemplate, acting like a fixed item. Just ensure that the Grid and the ListView have the same Width.

Comment: Hey Alexandre thanks for helping me out with this issue but still as i said in my main question that i don't want to use EXPLICIT WIDTH in my code. 
I have also edited my CODE in the main question where you can see that there is a Grid that changes its size with the Screen and have No width property.

Comment: Example if a user opens the application in 32 Inch Monitor the screen auto adjust to that one or in 24 inch Monitor it shouldn't matter, my screen adjust to all of them so giving explicit width doesn't solve my problem.
The Width i have used in my code is in the child of DataTemplate, Grid was to just check it that it might work but it doesn't.

Comment: You can avoid setting explicitly the Width by setting HorizontalAlignment="Stretch", VerticalAlignment="Stretch" and Margin="12,12,12,12". See edit in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your column definitions should be percentages, not whole values.

```
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
   <ColumnDefinition Width=".8*"/>
   <ColumnDefinition Width=".1*"/>
   <ColumnDefinition Width=".1*"/>
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

`.8 = 80%` `.1 = 10%` `.1 = 10%` **Total = 100%**

Your definitions are:

`3 = 300%` `1 = 100%` `1 = 100%` **Total = 500% !!**